# RabbitMQ how to split jobs to tasks and handle results

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have the following use case on a Spring-based Web application:

- I need to apply the Competing Consumers EIP with the following twists: the messages in the queue are actually split tasks belonging to the same job. Therefore, I need to properly track when all tasks of a job get completed and their completion status in order to save the scenario either as COMPLETED or FAILED, log the outcome and notify by e.g. e-mail the users accordingly

So, given the requirements I described above, my question is:

1. Can this be done with RabbitMQ and if yes how?

Comment: In that case I would simply put a unique ID per job, attach this ID to every message in the queue related to the job, put a status flag on each task as "In Progress", and on the last one "Completed". You just have to define what "Fail" means and implement the rules accordingly

Comment: @asettouf - if I follow the "Competing Consumers" pattern a.k.a "
Work Queues" https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html, the tasks of the job will be executed in parallel and this it what I need. So, taking this into consideration I don't see how your proposal can work

Comment: By the way, if someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. It helps keep the focus on unanswered questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a quick [gist](https://gist.github.com/asettouf/4c850020d3752fef093dbab32b2885cf) to show a very crude example of how one could do it. In this example, there is one producer and 2 consumers, 2 queues, one for sending by the producer ("SEND"), consumed by the consumers, and vice versa, consumers publish to the "RECV" queue and is consumed by the producer.

Now bear in mind this is a pretty crude example, as the Producer in that case send simply one job (a random amount of tasks between 0 and 5), and block until the job is done. A way to circumvent this would be to store in a Map a job id and the number of tasks, and every time check that the number of tasks done reported per job id.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I will try to evaluate as soon as possible, seems like a useful answer that can be accepted.

Comment: @kmandalas No problem, let me know if you want the full project, though the pom.xml is pretty straightforward. Also keep in mind that I did not try to improve or make it as efficient as possible, please take it more as a proof of concept

Comment: I think your idea is a logical PoC. Now, I try to link it with what I had discovered on this site: http://blog.zenika.com/2012/03/15/pdf-workers-with-rabbitmq since I am using Spring and associated frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is beyond the scope of RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ is for sending and receiving messages with ability to queue them.
It can't track your job tasks for you.

You will need to have a "Job Storage" service. Whenever your consumer finishes the task, its updates the Job Storage service, marking task as done. Job storage service knows about how many tasks are in the job, and when last task is done, completes jobs as succeeded. There in this service, you will also implement all your other business logic, such as when to treat job as failed.

Comment: Of course there will be need for implementing services. However after further research, I see that by combining "Work Queue" with "Request-Reply" patter and of course with some services I can approach a solution. See for example: https://blog.zenika.com/2012/03/15/pdf-workers-with-rabbitmq/

Comment: If something needs to happen on publisher side after consumer processed the message, yes consumer can send response back to publisher.